# Error in broadcast in python while doing matrix addition

Tags: python, numpy

```
E = 2e10  # Young's Modulus (kg/m^2)
L = 28    # Length of the bar (m)
while True:
    # Define Problem
    no_elements = int(input("Enter the number of elements: "))
    no_nodes_per_element = 3
    no_nodes = no_elements * (no_nodes_per_element - 1) + 1
    print (no_nodes)
    element_length = L / no_elements
    element_length = np.ones(no_elements) * element_length
    mid = np.cumsum(element_length) - element_length / 2
    node_length = L / (no_nodes-1)
    A = lambda x: (11/19600) * x**2 - (19/700) * x + 0.36  # Area equation
    elem_areas = A(mid)

# Stiffness Matrix of elements
    elementStiffnessMatrices = []
    for i in range( no_elements):
        A_e = elem_areas[i-1]
        E_e = E
        Le = element_length[i-1]
    # Modified stiffness matrix for a truss element with 3 nodes
        Ke_element = (A_e * E_e / (3 * Le)) * np.array([[7, -8, 1], [-8, 16, -8], [1, -8, 7]])
        elementStiffnessMatrices.append(Ke_element)
# Global Stiffness Matrix
    K_global = np.zeros((no_nodes, no_nodes))
    for i in range(no_elements):
        node1 = (i - 1) * 2 + 1
        node2 = (i - 1) * 2 + 2
        node3 = (i) * 2 + 1
        K_global[node1:node3+1, node1:node3+1] += elementStiffnessMatrices[i]


    K_original = K_global.copy()
    print(K_original)


# Forces
    appliedLoadpermeter = 2000  # Given line load is 2000 kg/m

    EEnodalForces = np.zeros((no_elements, 3))

    for i in range(no_elements):
        Le = element_length[i]
    # Energy Equivalent Nodal Forces for truss element with 3 nodes
        EEnodalForces[i, :] = (appliedLoadpermeter * Le / 2) * np.array([1, 1, 1])
    globalEENodalForces = np.zeros(no_nodes)
    for i in range(no_elements):
        node1 = (i - 1) * 2 + 1
        node2 = (i - 1) * 2 + 2
        node3 = i * 2 + 1
        indices = [node1, node2, node3]
        globalEENodalForces[indices] += EEnodalForces[i, :]
    F_original = globalEENodalForces.copy()


# Applying Boundary conditions
    Fixedsupport = 1
# Delete the rows and columns corresponding to the fixed support
    K_global = np.delete(K_global, 0, axis=0)
    K_global = np.delete(K_global, 0, axis=1)
    globalEENodalForces = np.delete(globalEENodalForces, 0)


# Solve for displacements
    Displacement = np.linalg.solve(K_global, globalEENodalForces)
    Displacement = np.insert(Displacement, 0, 0)


# Stress
    elem_Stress = np.zeros((no_elements, 3))
    for i in range(1, no_elements):
        u1 = Displacement[(i - 1) * 2 + 1]
        u2 = Displacement[(i - 1) * 2 + 2]
        u3 = Displacement[i * 2 + 1]
        Le = element_length[i - 1]
        Stress = E * np.array([[-3/Le, 4/Le, -1/Le],
                               [-1/Le, 0, 1/Le],
                                [1/Le, -4/Le, 3/Le]]) @ np.array([u1, u2, u3])
        elem_Stress[i - 1, 0] = Stress[0]
        elem_Stress[i - 1, 1] = Stress[1]
        elem_Stress[i - 1, 2] = Stress[2]
                       
################################################################################
# Step-9: Exact Values
# Equation of the displacment for Exact solution
    def U_x(x):
        return - (49 * np.log(11 * x**2 - 532 * x + 7056)) / 550000 - (21 * 5**(1/2) * 7**(1/2) * np.arctan((19 * 5**(1/2) * 7**(1/2)) / 35 - (11 * 5**(1/2) * 7**(1/2) * x) / 490)) / 1375000 + 9.0415e-4

#Equation of the Stress for Exact solution
    def S_x(x) : return (-2000*x + 56000)/((11/19600)*x**2 - (19/700)*x + 0.36)

################################################################################
# Displacement figure
    AXIS = np.arange(0, L + node_length, node_length)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(AXIS, Displacement, "b")
    plt.plot(np.arange(0, L + 0.1, 0.1), U_x(np.arange(0, L + 0.1, 0.1)), "r")
    plt.legend(["FE", "Exact"])
    plt.xlabel("Length of element (m)")
    plt.ylabel("Displacement (m)")
    plt.xlim([0, 28])
    plt.show()

# Stress figure

    plt.figure(2)
    for i in range(no_elements):
        a = mid[i] - element_length[i] / 2
        b = mid[i] + element_length[i] / 2
        plt.plot(np.linspace(a, b, 100), elem_Stress[i, 1] * np.ones(100), "b", label="FE", linewidth=2)   
    plt.plot(np.arange(0, L + 0.1, 0.1), S_x(np.arange(0, L + 0.1, 0.1)), "r", label="Exact", linewidth=2)
    plt.legend()
    plt.xlabel("Length of the element (m)")
    plt.ylabel("Stress (kg/m2)")
    plt.title("Comparison of FE Stress and Exact Solution")
    plt.show()
```

In this code the error shows as
Exception has occurred: ValueError
operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,0) (3,3) (0,0)
File "D:\CE\UTA Study Files\Finite Project\Finiteelementproject_3nodes.py", line 35, in 
K_global[node1:node3+1, node1:node3+1] += elementStiffnessMatrices[i]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (0,0) (3,3) (0,0)

Dont know how to put the correct matrix addition equation

Comment: It looks like the slices `node1:node3+1, node1:node3+1` are leading to your problem; apparently, node1>=node3+1, hence the submatrix `K_global[node1:node3+1, node1:node3+1]` has size (0,0).

Comment: What would be the best to keep instead of node1:node3+1